# Python math code greater than and less than not working

Tags: python, if-statement, syntax-error

```
import numpy as np
import random
i = random.randint(1,100)
if i > 0 and i <16:
    print ("Broken")
else if i > 16 and i > 100
    print ("Not broken")
```

I am trying to make it if the number is between 1 to 15 the racquet is broken but if it is 16-100 it is not broken.
It says it is invalid syntax in python.
Why is it invalid syntax?

Comment: Use `elif` (followed by the new condition then a colon), not `else if`.

Comment: `if i > 16 and i > 100` is similar to `if i > 100`. I think you meant to write `if i > 16 and i < 100`

Answer (score 1):

You've got 2 SyntaxErrors:

- There is no `else if` in Python, just [`elif`](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#if-statements)
- You [need a `:` after the conditions](https://docs.python.org/faq/design.html#why-are-colons-required-for-the-if-while-def-class-statements).

And a logical mistake:

- `i > 100` can never be `True`.

Then you also don't need `and` here, you could just use:

```
import random
i = random.randint(1,100)
if i < 16:
    print ("Broken")
else:
    print ("Not broken")
```

There is also the shortened version of `i > 0 and i < 16`:

```
if 0 < i < 16:
    print ("Broken")
elif 16 < i <= 100:  # compare to "<= 100" instead of "> 100"
    print ("Not broken")
```

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be trying to "fold" a nested `if` statement into its containing `if` statement, C-style:

```
if (i > 0 && i < 16)
    printf("Broken\n");
else
    if (i > 16 && i < 100)
        printf("Not broken\n");
```

Because the whitespace isn't significant, the above is equivalent to

```
if (i > 0 && i < 16)
    printf("Broken\n");
else if (i > 16 && i < 100)
    printf("Not broken\n");
```

giving the illusion of an `else if` clause.

---

In Python, indentation *is* significant, so you can't pull the same trick as in C. Instead, Python has an explicit `elif` clause that you can use to check multiple conditions in a single `if` statement.

```
if i > 0 and i < 16:
    print("Broken")
elif i > 16 and i < 100:
    print("Not broken")
```

This is semantically equivalent to

```
if i > 0 and i < 16:
    print("Broken")
else:
    if i > 16 and i < 100:
        print("Not broken")
```

but nicer looking.

Answer (score -2):

In Python, you use `elif` instead of `else if`. You also need a colon at the end of your else if line.

Answer (score -2):

It should be:

```
elif i > 16 and i > 100:
```

elif and with ":" in the end